# Thousands of unused images in wp media

Tags: wordpress, image, media, bulk

i would like to ask about any ideas how to delete almost 120 000+ unused images in wordpress media library. Friend asked me to help him with this issue on his woocommerce web.

I tried [Media Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/) or [Media Deduper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-deduper/).
But it's very slow process while you are able to delete max 250 images per page.

I have used sql command before, which deleted all media in wordpress.
But this time i would like to delete just unattached images which are't used. Most of them are product images which they don't have anymore.

I have one alternative solution i found, i have opened 4(i'll try more) browser tabs with clear link of listem images, 250 images per page. So i opened the same link on 3 tabs, nad every tab had different page, i pressed delete on all 3 tabs, and instead of 250 images i deleted 750 at the same time.
But there is also many duplicities.

Have anyone been solving this kind of issue before?
I would like to avoid deletion of all images and eshop maintance.

Thank you guyz.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-cleanup/

Comment: I tried that, didn't help, now i also have to clean the media trash... which by disabling him it the trash will not get deleted..